# Displaying Revit model in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, revit-api

I am currently working on a project that takes sensor measurements and then displays their values and controls them. This is pretty simple stuff. The sensors are place though out a house in the walls and ceiling. I have a Revit plans of the house and this is where I am having difficulties. From what read of the Revit API you can make plugins for the program but no one is using it to get the functionality to display the models (nothing major just zooming and rotating)in there own applicaitons. I am looking for any kind a solution that you think will help me. If this is not supported in the API can you suggest a way of drawing a model with DirectX or OpenGL.

Comment: In Revit 2013 API you can use WPF control to show Revit model in your Add-in. But I didn't try this feature myself. http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/03/revit-2013-and-its-api.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a new sample in the Revit 2013 SDK which shows off the Revit View WPF API, which does what you want.

Jeremy writes about the sample here:
http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/03/new-revit-2013-sdk-samples.html#4